# admob plugin error in cordova

Tags: android, cordova

i download the sample cordova admob project from github. i extracted and tested in android studio and debug on a galaxy s4. when the app opens it brings an alert"admob plugin not loaded". I've install the admob plugin, together with the internet plugin in my project

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width" />
    <title>Hello World</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        html, body { width:100%; height:100%; margin:0; padding:0; overflow:hidden; background-color:white; }
        div#fullpage { width:100%; height:100%; margin:0; padding:0; border:0px solid red; text-align:center; vertical-align:middle; }
        button { font-size: 22px; }
    </style>
</head>
<body onload="onDocLoad()" onresize="onResize()">
<script>
    function onDocLoad() {
        if(( /(ipad|iphone|ipod|android|windows phone)/i.test(navigator.userAgent) )) {
            document.addEventListener('deviceready', initApp, false);
        } else {
            initApp();
        }
    }

    function initApp() {
        initAd();

        // display the banner at startup
        window.plugins.AdMob.createBannerView();
    }
    function initAd(){
        if ( window.plugins && window.plugins.AdMob ) {
            var ad_units = {
                ios : {
                    banner: 'ca-app-pub-6869992474017983/4806197152',
                    interstitial: 'ca-app-pub-6869992474017983/7563979554'
                },
                android : {
                    banner: 'ca-app-pub-6869992474017983/9375997553',
                    interstitial: 'ca-app-pub-6869992474017983/1657046752'
                },
                wp8 : {
                    banner: 'ca-app-pub-6869992474017983/8878394753',
                    interstitial: 'ca-app-pub-6869992474017983/1355127956'
                }
            };
            var admobid = "";
            if( /(android)/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
                admobid = ad_units.android;
            } else if(/(iphone|ipad)/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
                admobid = ad_units.ios;
            } else {
                admobid = ad_units.wp8;
            }

            window.plugins.AdMob.setOptions( {
                publisherId: admobid.banner,
                interstitialAdId: admobid.interstitial,
                bannerAtTop: false, // set to true, to put banner at top
                overlap: false, // set to true, to allow banner overlap webview
                offsetTopBar: false, // set to true to avoid ios7 status bar overlap
                isTesting: false, // receiving test ad
                autoShow: true // auto show interstitial ad when loaded
            });

            registerAdEvents();

        } else {
            alert( 'admob plugin not ready' );
        }
    }
    // optional, in case respond to events
    function registerAdEvents() {
        document.addEventListener('onReceiveAd', function(){});
        document.addEventListener('onFailedToReceiveAd', function(data){});
        document.addEventListener('onPresentAd', function(){});
        document.addEventListener('onDismissAd', function(){ });
        document.addEventListener('onLeaveToAd', function(){ });
        document.addEventListener('onReceiveInterstitialAd', function(){ });
        document.addEventListener('onPresentInterstitialAd', function(){ });
        document.addEventListener('onDismissInterstitialAd', function(){ });
    }
    function onResize() {
        var msg = 'web view: ' + window.innerWidth + ' x ' + window.innerHeight;
        document.getElementById('sizeinfo').innerHTML = msg;
    }
    </script>
<div id="fullpage">
    <p>Demo for AdMob Plugin</p>
    <p><button onclick="window.plugins.AdMob.createBannerView();">create Ad</button> <button onclick="window.plugins.AdMob.destroyBannerView();">remove Ad</button></p>
    <p><button onclick="window.plugins.AdMob.showAd(true,function(){},function(e){alert(JSON.stringify(e));});">show Ad</button> <button onclick="window.plugins.AdMob.showAd(false);">hide Ad</button></p>
    <p><button onclick="window.plugins.AdMob.createInterstitialView();">create Interstitial Ad</button></p>
    <p><button onclick="window.plugins.AdMob.showInterstitialAd(true,function(){},function(e){alert(JSON.stringify(e));});">show Interstitial Ad</button></p>
    <div id="sizeinfo">width * height</div>
    <div>Try rotate screen to test the orientation change</div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't specify the actual admob plugin you use, I can answer using another plugin (https://github.com/sunnycupertino/cordova-plugin-admob-simple) that does what you need:

to add the plugin

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-admob-simple
```

Integration is as follows:

-Add the following javascript functions, put in your own ad code, play with the variables if you want.

-Call initAd() from onDeviceReady(), and showBannerFunc() and showInterstitialFunc() to show ads.

```
//initialize the goodies
function initAd(){
        if ( window.plugins && window.plugins.AdMob ) {
            var ad_units = {
                ios : {
                    banner: 'ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxx',       //PUT ADMOB ADCODE HERE
                    interstitial: 'ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxx'  //PUT ADMOB ADCODE HERE
                },
                android : {
                    banner: 'ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxx',       //PUT ADMOB ADCODE HERE
                    interstitial: 'ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxx'  //PUT ADMOB ADCODE HERE
                }
            };
            var admobid = ( /(android)/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) ? ad_units.android : ad_units.ios;

            window.plugins.AdMob.setOptions( {
                publisherId: admobid.banner,
                interstitialAdId: admobid.interstitial,
                adSize: window.plugins.AdMob.AD_SIZE.SMART_BANNER,  //use SMART_BANNER, BANNER, IAB_MRECT, IAB_BANNER, IAB_LEADERBOARD
                bannerAtTop: false, // set to true, to put banner at top
                overlap: true, // banner will overlap webview 
                offsetTopBar: false, // set to true to avoid ios7 status bar overlap
                isTesting: false, // receiving test ad
                autoShow: false // auto show interstitial ad when loaded
            });

            registerAdEvents();
            window.plugins.AdMob.createInterstitialView();  //get the interstitials ready to be shown
            window.plugins.AdMob.requestInterstitialAd();

        } else {
            //alert( 'admob plugin not ready' );
        }
}
//functions to allow you to know when ads are shown, etc.
function registerAdEvents() {
        document.addEventListener('onReceiveAd', function(){});
        document.addEventListener('onFailedToReceiveAd', function(data){});
        document.addEventListener('onPresentAd', function(){});
        document.addEventListener('onDismissAd', function(){ });
        document.addEventListener('onLeaveToAd', function(){ });
        document.addEventListener('onReceiveInterstitialAd', function(){ });
        document.addEventListener('onPresentInterstitialAd', function(){ });
        document.addEventListener('onDismissInterstitialAd', function(){
            window.plugins.AdMob.createInterstitialView();          //REMOVE THESE 2 LINES IF USING AUTOSHOW
            window.plugins.AdMob.requestInterstitialAd();           //get the next one ready only after the current one is closed
        });
    }

//display the banner
function showBannerFunc(){
    window.plugins.AdMob.createBannerView();
}
//display the interstitial
function showInterstitialFunc(){
    window.plugins.AdMob.showInterstitialAd();
}
```